# Where can I find my product key for Black Ops 3?

Tags: steam, pc

So I bought a Call of Duty Black Ops 3 game for PC at EB Games. When I put it in the disc drive and opened the link, it opened Steam and asked for a product code. Only problem is that I don't know what a Product Code is.

Answer (score 2):

A product code is a series of numbers/letters separated by dashes, like: `AS79C-AF9KV-VIE30`.

Search the contents of the box that the game came in for something that looks kinda like that. It is generally found on the sleeve for the CD.